# Convert MTEF to MathML

Tags: c#, equation, mathml, mathtype

I use SDK *DSSCI* (*MathType*) for *MTEF* -> *MML* formula conversion, in WEB C# application.

Conversion is well performed from *DLL* function, with string input (code *MTEF*) and string output (code *MathML*), but I see that *MathType* EXE is ever runned and closed from my application.

If *MathType* is NOT installed, the function DOESN'T work. Is it possible to obtain conversion, only with deployed SDK DLL (`MTSDKDN.dll` and `MT6.dll`), without installing *MathType* on the WEB server?

Answer (score 0):

The conversion from MTEF to MathML is actually done by MathType itself, so no. (Sorry for the very delayed response. This one showed up in my feeds only this morning.)

Bob Mathews, Design Science